# Ionic 2 RC.0 [Ts] Cannot Find Module ./App.Module.Ngfactory

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm getting this error on the src/app/main.prod.ts page. The app builds fine but this TS error is driving me crazy.

I uninstalled and reinstalled node, npm and ionic. I went directly into the user files as well to make sure it was "clean" uninstalled.

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.7.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014 
NPM: 3.10.8

Answer (score 0):

Look like there still fixing the issue.

[https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ts-cannot-find-module-app-module-ngfactory/64968/1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ts-cannot-find-module-app-module-ngfactory/64968/16)6

[Edited]

After browse for few days, actually is not really a problem. It will hit the error, when you doing the development. Until you build into the mobile, by using command `ionic build ios` or `ionic run android`, it will trigger the `main.prod.ts`.

If you cannot build into the mobile, use `npm run build` to check all the errors and fixed that.

That's it !!!